# keep value when item costs more

Tags: c++

Made a candy machine program for school. problem is when one item costs more than I have it still takes away my money down to zero but dont take away the item thoug.

heres my code

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int money = 30;
    int x = 15;
    char input;
    int japp = 5;
    int daim = 7;
    int cocacola = 10;
    int fanta = 10;


    cout << " Welcome to my candy machine" << endl;
    cout << " choose one of the following items" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    while (x != 22)


    {


        if (money <= 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Your have no money left!!  therefore you cant shop anymore " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            money = 0;

        }






        cout << "Slott 1 JAPP  " << japp << "  10 kronor" << endl;
        cout << "Slott 2 Daim  " << daim <<"  10 kronor"<< endl;
        cout << "Slott 3 coca cola  " << cocacola <<"  15 kronor "<< endl;
        cout << "Slott 4 Fanta  " << fanta <<"  15 kronor"<< endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << " you have " << money << " kronor left" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "abort [A]" << endl;


        cin >> input;
        switch (input)
        {
        case '1':


             if (japp <= 5)
            {

                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
                japp--;
                money -= 10;

            }
            if (japp <= 0)
            {
                cout << " there is no moore japp!!" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                japp = 0;
            }
            if (money <= -1)
            {
                japp++;
            }

            break;

        case '2':



            if (daim <= 7)
            {
                daim--;
                money -= 10;
            }

            if (daim <= 0)
            {
                cout << " there is no more daim !!" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                daim = 0;
            }

            if (money <= -1)
            {
                daim++;
            }
            break;

        case'3':
            if (cocacola <= 10)
            {
                cocacola--;
                money -= 15;
            }

            if (cocacola <= 0)
            {
                cout << "there is no more coke !!" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cocacola = 0;

            }
            if (money <= -1)
            {
                cocacola++;
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            if (fanta <= 10)
            {
                fanta--;
                money -= 15;
            }

            if (fanta <= 0)
            {
                cout << " there is no moore fanta !!" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                fanta = 0;

            }
            if (money <= -1)
            {
                fanta++;
            }
            break;
        case 'A':
            cout << " ending the game...." << endl;
            return 0;
        case 'a':
            cout << " ending the game.... " << endl;
            return 0;
        default:
            cout << " wrong option, pleas choose between option 1 - 4 " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            break;
        }

    }



    return 0;
}
```

thankful for any help I can get

Comment: Why are there so many downvotes on this post

Comment: Dunno.  I'm guessing at 'no aparrent attempt to debug':(

Comment: beginners have no idea how to do that and the guy atleast showed some effort his logic is a bit flawed nothing else seems wrong

Comment: @rahultyagi *"This question does not show any research effort"* is the first suggested reason to downvote a question.  If you hover your mouse over the downvote button, you will see that text.  I suspect that the downvotes are communicating that - no evidence of research or an actual useful question.

Comment: 'beginners have no idea how to do that' - then they should learn when progressing beyond 'Hello World', instead of posting on SO as the first option.

Comment: @DrewDormann I think it might discourage the OP from asking questions however since its necessary to maintain the quality so I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions are wrong eg

instead of

```
  if(japp<=5 )
```

you should do

```
  if(japp>0 && money >=10) // since japp>0 to buy it also since each japp 

  //costs 10 money , so money should also be greater than 10. Same for other products.
```

Also your condition

```
  if(money <-1) 
      japp++;
```

And

```
  if(jazz <= 0)
```

becomes unnecessary

Comment: worked as a charm thank you!